# Filling height using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is an age old question, although I wasn't able to find a solution that suited me.

Given a DIV inside a table cell (TD), I want to fill the DIV's height to fit the TD

```
+-----------+
|     TD    |
|+---------+|
||   DIV   ||
|+---------+|
|           |
+-----------+
```

Only gotchas are:

- I don't want to set the height of the parent TD
- I want to avoid using Javascript (prefer a CSS only solution)
- Keep the resizable nature of the contenteditable DIV
- Bonus: get it to work in IE8+ (cross browser solution)
- Bonus: use display:flex; - I couldn't work this out, but looks like it should do the trick.

Too much to ask?

**Example:**

Get the "foo" DIV, to fill 100% height of their parent TD. I got something close to working, but having padding on the DIV element, throws out the borders (using Opera).

```
/* My Attempt: close, but the padding throws out the borders */
div{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nickg1/g5cpQ/5/

Thanks!

Comment: use `display:table-cell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, as per you terms and conditions, `display:table` is the best solution for you.

Add css like this :

```
div{
display:table;
height: 100%;
border:1px solid red;    
}
```

Check following link for

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AkjND/5/)

Comment: Unfortunately, As per your requirement i've not found anything for IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```css
table {
    height: 1px;
}
td {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
}
div{
    border:1px solid red;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* My Attempt: close, but the padding throws out the borders */
div{
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/AkjND/

The trick is to specify a height on the table, any small value will do the trick.

If you want to apply vertical padding to the inner `div`, you need to use `box-sizing: border-box`, which may work as far back as IE8.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Hey, looks great (`table{height:1px;}` is what fixes it)! Unfortunately this trick squashes the table in IE(8). I know it was a bonus, but I don't suppose you have any other tricks up your sleeve to account for IE as well?

Comment: I did not test in IE8, and the result is a bit baffling since tables are not suppose to collapse to nothing.  Instead of specifying a height on the table, try setting a small height on the table cells.  Make sure that IE8 is not running in quirks mode.

Comment: I think that the solution by @husen may be more robust.  It may work better in IE8.